# How to use Jsoup to get the number of Elements containing a certain img?

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I have been stuck with this for a while any help is really appreciated.

Problem:

I want to be able to retrieve and get the count/size of elements only containing a certain image.

Website to be retireved from:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/notice-to-mariners/").timeout(600000).get();
```

Element/img to be retrieved/counted from multiple classes, (inside the stars)

```
**<img src="/images/in_force.jpg"** alt="Notice to Mariners No. 95 of 2013 - Cancellation of Notice in Force">
```

Which is inside other classes all with the same name of:

```
 <div class="news_main">
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the selector documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

I can't test this at the moment, but I think `doc.select("img[src~=.*in_force.jpg]");` might be along the lines of what you're looking for. That'll get you an `Elements` object; counting the individual elements is an exercise left to the reader :).

**Edit**

To count the divs containing one or more of those img elements, you might want `doc.select("div.news_main > img[src~=.*in_force.jpg]")` instead.

Comment: You don't actually have to count them manually, Elements is a Collection<Element>, it has a `size()` method.

Comment: hi Space Pope, thanks for your answer, will be trying it on for size() shortly......I was was aware of the size() method but with all the options I had tried I kept getting 0.

Comment: Hi, I still get a 0 with this, is there something I'm missing... Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/notice-to-mariners/").timeout(600000).get();
           
           Elements elements = doc.select("div.news_main > img[src~=.*in_force.jpg]");
           
           for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++ ){
             elements.get(i);
            System.out.println("Sources of "+ i);

Comment: The page that you're trying to parse doesn't have the divs you're looking for when connecting via JSoup - I haven't looked through the source enough to find exactly what's causing the change, but they're delivering different content to browsers than to crawlers. To see what I mean, run your code in a debugger, and set a breakpoint right after the `Document doc...` line. Compare that text with what you get by going to the website and viewing its source.

Comment: ok thank you.... do you know of or is there a way to access the data? tutorials, examples etc? thanks

Comment: You probably want to get the site to think you're visiting via a browser, download the html, and parse that instead of trying to do it all through one Jsoup call. If you're not familiar with web scraping in general, I'd suggest Googling for some information about [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). I'd normally try to use cURL/wget for something like this, but I'd have to do a bit more research to see if it's practical for this particular site.